# Missing a Temporary Folder

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I'm working on a mac OSX 10.8 using the built in apache server and php/mysql to develop on moodle 2.4

the problem i'm having is that why I try and upload anything I get the error message PHP is missing a Temporary Folder.

I then downloaded the live copy onto my laptop as i know this is working, and still got the same error on my localhost.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open your php.ini file look at the value for `upload_tmp_dir` and double check that the path exists. 
And that apache has write access to it also, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, on windows refer to the same upload_tmp_dir setting in your php.ini file and make sure the IUSR account has full control/write access to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I suggest the problem could be with `open_base_dir` **php.ini** constant. If this constant has some value.

### Probable Solution 1

You could delete `open_basedir` param. Probably, this move could solve the problem.

### Probable Solution 2

The above solution in some cases could be dangerous.
I recommend to append `:/tmp` instead of deleting open_basedir if
`open_basedir` presented. This move could be completed by adding **PHP** temp dir after colon to `open_basedir`:

```
open_basedir = "old-path:/tmp"
```

Then, restart php7.2-fpm with a terminal command

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

Or your **PHP** version.

```
sudo service php7.x-fpm restart
```

Usually, php.ini path could be detected by calling phpinfo() and navigating
`ini_path` block.

Answer (score -3):

Change permission on /tmp folder
chmod 777 /tmp

Comment: You shouldn't have execution set on /tmp. This needs to go away.