# Missing a temporary folder. in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

when i am trying to upload images from wp-admin it shows **Missing a temporary folder.**

I have tried php.ini for tmp folder but php.ini is not working. Is there any solution?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235871/missing-a-temporary-folder

Comment: I have already tried these but php.ini, chmod none resolve the problem.