# The temporary folder is missing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, temporary, temp

I am using Codeigniter 3
and uploading a file using upload library in CodeIgniter whenever I upload the file it's giving me `The temporary folder is missing`.
I am confusing why it's giving me this error because I uploaded my project on a server its working fine on that server but when I upload same files on another server it's giving me this error I don't why.
Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="storecreatewrapper">
    <div class="toptext">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Let's build your store at <span><?php echo PROJECT;?>!</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="formwrapper">
        <form action="<?php echo site_url('shop/addshop')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="adsp_09">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="mianstoreform">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="formtopimg">
                                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logos/storepic.png') ?>" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="mainbasictxt">
                                    <div class="bsichr"></div>
                                    <div class="basictxt">
                                        <p>Basic Shop Information</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <?php c_error();?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="stformfields">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Shop Name <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                       <?php 
                                            $shopname = array(
                                                    'class' => 'form-control',
                                                    'id' => 'shopname',
                                                    'placeholder' => 'Shop Name',
                                                    'name'=>'shopname'
                                                    );
                                            echo form_input($shopname);
                                        ?>   
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Shop URL <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <?php 
                                            $shopurl = array(
                                                    'class' => 'form-control',
                                                    'id' => 'fohopurl',
                                                    'name'=>'shpurl',
                                                    'placeholder' => 'Shop URL: www.'.PROJECT.'.com/shops/URL'
                                                    );
                                            echo form_input($shopurl);
                                        ?>    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custmhr"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="mainbasictxt">
                                    <div class="bsichr"></div>
                                    <div class="basictxt">
                                        <p>Account Verification Detail</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="frmrads">
                                    <div class="pull-left cusradhead">
                                        Account Type:
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <div class="radio">
                                          <label>
                                            <input class="act_9" type="radio" name="at" id="individual" value="individual" checked>
                                             Individual Professional.
                                          </label>
                                        </div>                                      
                                        <div class="radio">
                                          <label>
                                            <input  class="act_9" type="radio" name="at" id="business" value="business">
                                             Business (Selling On Behalf of a Business Entity).
                                          </label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="documtslt">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 lftcolset">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <select name="dcname" id="dcm_67">
                                                    <option selected="select">
                                                        Document (Please Select)
                                                    </option>
                                                    <option value="national id">National ID</option>
                                                    <option value="passport">Passport</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 rytcolset">
                                            <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="ushplg" style="display:none"/>
                                            <button type="button"  id="upfile1" class="btn cutsltbtn" for="file-upload">Image</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="docfrmffl">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <?php 
                                            $shopurl = array(
                                                    'class' => 'form-control',
                                                    'id' => 'document_id',
                                                    'placeholder' => 'Document ID',
                                                    'name'=>'document_id'
                                                    );
                                            echo form_input($shopurl);
                                        ?>   
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p class="notetxt">
                                        Note: English (a-z,A-Z), digits(0-9), - , spaces.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <?php 
                                            $shopurl = array(
                                                    'class' => 'form-control expiry_date',
                                                    'id' => 'datepicker',
                                                    'placeholder' => 'Expiry Date',
                                                    'name'=>'expiry_date'
                                                    );
                                            echo form_input($shopurl);
                                        ?>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p class="notetxt">
                                        Note: JPEG, PNG or PDF only and 2MB file size.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custmhr"></div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="mainbasictxt">
                                    <div class="bsichr"></div>
                                    <div class="basictxt">
                                        <p>Order Pickup Location</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="frmrads">
                                    <div class="pull-left">
                                        <?php if(is_logedin()): //if logedin ?>
                                            <?php if(
                                                $this->session->userdata('city_id') && $this->session->userdata('area_id') && $this->session->userdata('direction')
                                                ):
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                              <label>
                                                <input class="loc_09" type="radio" name="location" id="shipping" value="shipping" checked>
                                                Same as my shipping address
                                              </label>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php else: // if loggedin and city area and direction not found. ?>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                              <label>
                                                <input class="loc_09" type="radio" name="location" id="new_address" value="new_address" checked>
                                                Register a new address
                                              </label>
                                            </div>  
                                            <?php endif; //checking if shipping addres set or not..?>
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <div class="radio">
                                              <label>
                                                <input class="loc_09" type="radio" name="location" id="new_address" value="new_address" checked>
                                                Register a new address
                                              </label>
                                            </div>  
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="locations">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>City <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <select  name="city" class="city_9 sada" disabled>
                                            <option  value="none" selected="select">City</option>
                                            <?php if($cities->num_rows() > 0): 
                                                foreach ($cities->result() as $city):
                                            ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $city->c_id ?>">
                                                <?php echo $city->city_name ?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach;?>
                                            <?php endif;  ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Area <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <!-- <select name="area" id="area" class="sada" disabled>
                                            <option selected="select">Select Area</option>
                                        </select> -->
                                        <span class="pslare">

                                        </span>
                                        <input type="text"  class="form-control caresshx" id="areasped" placeholder="Area" value="">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="area" value="" id="ardix">   
                                        <!-- <select name="area" id="area" class="sada" <?php if($shop_info[0]['location'] == 1){ echo 'disabled';}?>>
                                            <option selected="select">Select Area</option>
                                        </select> -->
                                          <ul class="ullist list-unstyled">

                                          </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="docfrmffl">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control sada" name="street" id="street" placeholder="Street" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="build_num" class="form-control sada" placeholder="Building Name"  disabled id="build_num">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                         <?php
                                            $rft = array(
                                                    'class'=>'form-control',
                                                    'name'=>'rft',
                                                    'placeholder'=>'House Number' 
                                                );
                                            echo form_input($rft);
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Direction <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" name="direction" rows="3" id="flladdrs" placeholder="Direction"></textarea>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="shwnmap">Click here to choose from map</a>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="form-group tsslid" id="opmap" style="display: none">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <input id="address" type="text" placeholder="Enter an address" class="form-control">
                                           <!--  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="ncnmap" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a> -->
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="nmapok" class="btn btn-primary tbtn">Close map</a>
                                          </div>
                                          <div id="map"></div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="custmhr"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="mainbasictxt">
                                    <div class="bsichr"></div>
                                    <div class="basictxt">
                                        <p>Contact Information</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="docfrmffl">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>First Name <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <?php if(is_logedin()): ?>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo get_session_element('fname');?>" readonly id="fname">
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" id="fname">
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Last Name <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <?php if(is_logedin()): ?>
                                            <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo get_session_element('lname');?>" readonly id="lname">
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname">
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Email <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <?php if(is_logedin()): ?>
                                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo get_session_element('email');?>" readonly id="email">
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email">
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php if(!is_logedin()): ?>
                            <div class="row" class="lng" id="lng">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Password <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Enter You Password" class="form-control" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Confirm Password <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="password" id="cnpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" name="cnpass">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Mobile Phone <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <?php if(is_logedin()): ?>
                                            <input type="text" name="mob" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Phone" value="<?php echo get_session_element('mobile');?>" id="mob">
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <input type="text" name="mob" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Phone" id="mob">
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>LandLine <span class="red">*</span></label>
                                        <?php if(is_logedin()): ?>
                                            <input type="text" name="landline" class="form-control" placeholder="LandLine" value="<?php echo get_session_element('phone');?>" id="landline">
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                            <input type="text" name="landline" class="form-control" placeholder="LandLine" id="landline">
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="agreementtxt">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="arg_098"> 
                                        I have read and accepted terms and conditions of the agreement.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="createbtndv">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn custmsubmit edupfl" value="Create Store" disabled="disabled" id="btnsb">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group snofd">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            echo form_close();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
$image_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../assets/images/usershop');
                        $config['upload_path'] = $image_path;
                        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                        $config['file_name'] = random_string('alnum', 16);

                        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('ushplg'))
                            {
                                $error = $this->upload->display_errors('<p>','</p>');

                                c_flash('alert-danger',$error,'shop/open');

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $filename = $this->upload->data();
                                            $data['doc_image'] = $filename['file_name'];
                            }
                                $add_n_shop = $this->mod_shop->add_new_shop($data);
                                if ($add_n_shop)
                                {
                                    c_flash('alert-success','Your shop has been created but review by admin.','user/about');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    c_flash('alert-danger','Your shop has not been created.','shop/open');
                                }
```

Comment: Make sure you have assets out side of the application folder in the root directory `$config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/usershop/';`

Comment: I already have assets directory outside of the application directory and last thing I am using https

Comment: I am working on ci since 3 years it always works on every project but in this project, I am using php7 and https

Comment: Did you name the controllers class and file names correctly where the first letter only upper case on class and filenames explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: here is className class Shop extends CI_Controller

Comment: Might be something to do with htaccess? not sure

Comment: I am using php7 and SSL for this project and I am not sure SSL is conflicting or php7 that's why i asked a question on stack after a long time

Comment: read https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-36384.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/14235971/2275490

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when you run out of disk space or there don't have available inodes. In my case I faced this error because PHP session files were using up all the inodes.
The following answer can help you with further investigation:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1107896