# php cant upload file - Missing a temporary folder

Tags: php, cpanel

I have a file upload form that used to work without any problems but now gives the error

> Missing a temporary folder.

[Missing a Temporary Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235871/missing-a-temporary-folder)

According to the link above I added `upload_tmp_dir = "/ var / tmp"` to the `php.ini` file, but it still displays the same message and the file is not uploaded.

php v: 7.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing a Temporary Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235871/missing-a-temporary-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have the right solution, it looks like the path is just wrong.

I believe it should be

```
upload_tmp_dir = "/var/tmp"
```

Comment: Where should I made the ‍‍‍‍‍**tmp folder**? I made it in  ‍‍**www folder** in cpanel.